# Hapi - reply JSON only

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

How can I adjust the Hapi reply function such that it would reply JSON objects only?
Should I send it as plain and send? I seem not to find a good example

Here is some edit - added some sample code to understand what's happening.

The route:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/user/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        var ids = null;

        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT ID FROM Users;',function(err,rows,fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            ids = rows;
            // console.log(ids);
            reply(ids);
        });    
    }
});
```

The reply:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[{"ID":1},{"ID":2},{"ID":3},{"ID":4},{"ID":5},{"ID":6},{"ID":7},{"ID":8},{"ID":9},{"ID":10},{"ID":11},{"ID":12},{"ID":13},{"ID":14},{"ID":15},{"ID":16},{"ID":17},{"ID":18},{"ID":19},{"ID":20},{"ID":21}]
</pre></body></html>
```

Comment: Side note. There are no "JSON objects". JSON always is a string. You can turn it into an object by parsing it. After that point it is no longer JSON.

Comment: My guess? Your browser is converting the JSON for display. Hapi should be returning a JSON string as shown.

Comment: Yes, the browser wraps it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope I understand the question ok. Are we talking version 8.x ?  For me it seems the default. With this code as a route handler,

```
folders: {
    handler: function( request, reply ) {

        'use strict';
        reply({
            folders: folders
        }).code( 200 );

    }
},
```

and doing

```
curl http://localhost:3001/folders
```

I get the following output

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3001 (#0)
> GET /folders HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:3001
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< cache-control: no-cache
< content-length: 266
< accept-ranges: bytes
< Date: Tue, 03 Feb 2015 23:19:31 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{folders ..... }
```

Also, note that I only call `reply()`not `return reply()`

HTH

Comment: `return reply()` is a convention to indicate that the method is complete. See: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2168

Answer (score 4):

As for v17 and above, the **reply()** interface was removed. Now the handlers uses async functions, and you can just return the value.

From the [hapi docs](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3658) example:

```
// Before
const handler = function (request, reply) {
    return reply('ok');
};

// After
const handler = function (request, h) {
    return 'ok';
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Using hapi's `reply(data)` and passing a `data` object will do the work for you. Internally, hapi will create the appropriate JSON of your data object and respond it.

There's a tutorial on [how to reply JSON for a given request using hapi](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-reply-a-request-with-json) that might give some more insights.

Answer (score 0):

Using v17 and above, simply returning a naked string doesn't result in a json encoded reply.
Use `return JSON.stringify()` to ensure the string is json encoded

e.g.

```
function (request, h) {
    return JSON.stringify('ok');
};
```